# How to make the path of a symbolically linked directory the exactly the path of the original directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, symbolic-link

I have created a symbolic link on my desktop that links to my `/var/www/wordpress` dir via

```
$ ln -s /var/www/wordpress/ ~/Desktop/wordpress-link
```

When I open bash and `cd` into `~/Desktop/wordpress-link` I notice that the path is:

```
max@laptop:~/Desktop/wordpress-link
```

Running `pwd` shows me the same path as above. When I do `ls` I see asterixis next to most of the files. If I open a file in Sublime Text while in `max@laptop:~/Desktop/wwwordpress` I can see that the path of the file is actually `/var/www/wordpress/file-name.php` so I know I am linked to the proper file. The problem is that it just feels messed up to see bash telling me that I am in `~/Desktop/wordpress-link` when I am really in `/var/www/wordpress/`. Also the asterixis are unsettling.

Is there a way to make it so that when I `cd` or click into `~/Desktop/wordpress-link` that I will actually be in the linked dir and see `/var/www/wordpress` as my path name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way: `alias cd="cd -P"`

Comment: Are there any negative side effects of doing this that I might run into later down the road?

Comment: Only if you do this: `cd ~/Desktop; cd wordpress-link; cd ..` and expect to end up in your Desktop dir again.